# Changed Server Name Now Can't Connect to Configuration Database SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We recently changed the name of the server that SharePoint 2010 Foundation was running on and now we get the following message when trying to launch the central administration application:

"Cannot connect to the configuration database"

I looked up some resources and some noted to try stsadmin and run the renameserver command, but that didn't work.  The result read that the "Operation was successful".

Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Needed to do the following (fyi. adding a sql server alias didn't work for me).

1) Add a record to the host file that directs the localhost IP (127.0.0.1) to the old server name.

2) Add registry entries to allow the host entry to be recognized (if they don't exist you'll have to add them).

Computer\hkey_local_machine\system\currentcontrolset\services\lanmanserver\parameters
OptionalNames = OldServerName

Computer\hkey_local_machine\system\currentcontrolset\control\lsa\msv1_0
BackConnectionHostNames = OldServerName